# How can i toggle directive without using scope declaration

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, scope, angularjs-scope

I need to watch an attribute from a directive, and have that toggle a function whenever the value is true, this works the first time you click it, but i then need to reset the value of the ATTRIBUTE/Attribute model once it's evaluated, and that's the part i can't figure out.

DEMO OF ISSUE: https://jsfiddle.net/DG24c/200/

The desired outcome would be to have the `EXTERNAL ACCESS` button in my demo always trigger the alert method.

Template:

```
<div ng-controller="otherController">
    <button interactive show-when="toggled">Show Directive Alert</button>
    <button ng-click="toggled = true" >External access</button>
</div>
```

Javascript:

```
myApp.controller("otherController",function($scope){
   $scope.toggled = false;
});


myApp.directive('interactive', function($parse) {
    return {
    restrict : 'A',
    // scope : true || {} cannot be used
    link : function(scope, element,attrs) {

       element.on('click', function() {
        show();
       });

       scope.$watch(attrs.showWhen, function(newValue,o) {       
           if (newValue) {
               // the value is true, but now I need to reset
               // the value on TOGGLED back to false here, so that the next
               // time the button clicks, it will show the alert
               show();
               // tried attrs.$set('showWhen', false);
               // tried var showAttr = $parse(attrs.showWhen)();
               // showAttr = false;

           }
       });

       function show() {
           alert('showing!');
       }
    }
  };
})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
$parse(attrs.showWhen + ' = false')(scope);
```

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/DG24c/204/

Javascript:

```
myApp.directive('interactive', function($parse) {
  return {
    restrict : 'A',
    link : function(scope, element,attrs) {

       element.on('click', function() {
        show();
       });

       scope.$watch(function(inboundScope) {
           // gets the value of the attribute
           var interactive = $parse(attrs.showWhen)(inboundScope);
           if (!interactive) return false; // no need to continue if the value is already false
           $parse(attrs.showWhen + ' = false')(inboundScope); // updates parent scopes value back to false
           return interactive;           
       }, function(newValue) {
           if (newValue) show();
       });


       function show() {
           alert('showing!' + attrs.showWhen);
       }
    }
  };
});
```

HTML:

```
<div ng-app="myApp">
  <div ng-controller="myCtrl as $ctrl">
    <button interactive show-when="$ctrl.toggled">Show Directive Alert</button>
    <button ng-click="$ctrl.toggled = true" >External access</button>
    <pre>{{$ctrl.toggled | json}}</pre>

    <button interactive show-when="$ctrl.toggled2">Show Directive Alert2</button>
    <button ng-click="$ctrl.toggled2 = true" >External access2</button>
    <pre>{{$ctrl.toggled2 | json}}</pre>

  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: actually @jwpfox this did help me resolve it, I've edited his answer to elaborate

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't be using attributes like that, you need to use scope.  Not really sure what your comment `// scope : true || {} cannot be used` means though...why can't you?

It works just fine provided you actually use data binding with scope instead of just looking at an attribute: https://jsfiddle.net/DG24c/203/

```
myApp.directive('interactive', function($parse) {
    return {
    restrict : 'A',
    scope: {
      showWhen: '='
    },
    link : function(scope, element) {
       element.on('click', function() {
        show();
       });

       scope.$watch('showWhen', function(v,o) {
           if (v) {
               scope.showWhen = false;
               show();
           }
       });

       function show() {
           alert('showing!');
       }
    }
  };
})
```

Comment: Because i want to use this on other elements that also have an isolated scope so this will not work unfortunately